# How to disable all widgets in MainWindow recursively

Tags: c++, qt5

It is easy to disable a widget in Qt using `->setEnable(false)` but if I have a lot of widgets, then the process is tedious and error-prone. I've searched for this issue and found out `findChildren()`. I would like to use it to disable all widgets in the windows. The following modified code is not working

```
for (auto widget : findChildren<QMainWindow*>())
      if (! qobject_cast<QWidget*>(widget)) widget->setEnabled(false);
```

How can I modify the preceding code to disable all widgets in my MainWindow Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortest version:

```
mainWindow->setEnabled(false);
```

Disables the entire Window.

---

Shorter version of your code:

```
for(auto *widget : this->findChildren<QWidget *>())
{
    widget->setEnabled(false);
}
```

`findChildren` requires the type you'd like to find rather than the type  `QMainWindow`. Since GUI elements inherit `QWidget` you search for them.

Replace `this` with a pointer to your `QMainWindow` unless you implement this in said class.

---

Can also be turned into a function:

```
bool disable(QObject *object)
{
    auto success { false };

    if(object)
    {
        for(auto *widget : object->findChildren<QWidget *>())
        {
            widget->setEnabled(false);
        }

        success = true;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Then call `disable(this);` in your `QMainWindow`.

---

`findChildren<QWidget *>(QRegularExpression { "p.*" }) // to disable all items starting with "p"`

`findChildren` also takes a regular expression so if you only want to disable certain items you could specify something unique in their name and select them like that.

---

Longer version:

```
void disableAll(QObject *item)
{
    if(item)
    {
        auto children { item->children() };

        for(auto *child : children)
        {
            auto *widget { qobject_cast<QWidget *>(child) };

            if(widget)
            {
                // recursive approach might / shouldn't be needed
                // as all children of each item automatically get disabled
                // if their parent is disabled.
                disableAll(child);

                widget->setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it in your window like this `disableAll(this);` or simply by passing a pointer to the element where you'd like to start disabling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The shortest version doesn't allow me to enable the button again. Any suggestions!

Comment: @CroCo That's because the parent is still disabled. If you want specific elements to be disabled rather than all you'll have to replace the `QWidget *` part with for example `this->findChildren<QPushButton *>()`, which will then disable all `QPushButton` only.

Comment: That worked thanks again but this solution is a bit tedious since  I need to consider all widgets (i.e. QPushButton, QTextEdit, ..., etc) in my GUI. Is there an advanced approach to handle that in a single call?

Comment: @CroCo I've updated my post, check the "regular expression" part. I can't think of anything simpler.

Comment: Thank you. I've ended up using this `void disableAllQPushButton(MainWindow* obj)
{
    for(auto *widget : obj->findChildren<QPushButton*>())
        widget->setEnabled(false);
}` with a call as `disableAllQPushButton(this);`